# How to click a button making reference to a different element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and yesterday I came across a problem and I can't find the solution. So, I have a page with a button that I need to click but this page have other buttons with the same name.

See image below:

[image: See image below]

I was trying to do something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath(("//span[@class='slider round'] and //td[contains(.,'célula 1')]"));
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div _ngcontent-c8="">

        <table _ngcontent-c8="" class="table w-100">
            <thead _ngcontent-c8="">
                <tr _ngcontent-c8="" align="center" height="50">
                    <th _ngcontent-c8="">Nome</th>
                    <th _ngcontent-c8="" colspan="7">Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody _ngcontent-c8="">
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><tr _ngcontent-c8="" align="center">
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">célula 1</td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <label _ngcontent-c8="" class="switch" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Desativar célula">
                            <input _ngcontent-c8="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-model="1" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-primary" ngbtooltip="Alterar célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Alterar célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-danger" ngbtooltip="Apagar célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Apagar célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-info" ngbtooltip="Configuração de célula" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/configuracao-celula" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Configuração de célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-wrench"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-secondary" ngbtooltip="Campos da célula" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/campos" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Campos da célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-list"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-dark" ngbtooltip="Tabulações da célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Tabulações da célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-bookmark"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-warning" ngbtooltip="Configurar Pausa" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/motivos-pausa,1" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Configurar Pausa">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-media-pause"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr _ngcontent-c8="" align="center">
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">célula 2</td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <label _ngcontent-c8="" class="switch" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Desativar célula">
                            <input _ngcontent-c8="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-model="1" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-primary" ngbtooltip="Alterar célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Alterar célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-danger" ngbtooltip="Apagar célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Apagar célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-info" ngbtooltip="Configuração de célula" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/configuracao-celula" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Configuração de célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-wrench"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-secondary" ngbtooltip="Campos da célula" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/campos" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Campos da célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-list"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-dark" ngbtooltip="Tabulações da célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Tabulações da célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-bookmark"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-warning" ngbtooltip="Configurar Pausa" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/motivos-pausa,2" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Configurar Pausa">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-media-pause"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr _ngcontent-c8="" align="center">
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">célula 3</td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <label _ngcontent-c8="" class="switch" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Ativar célula">
                            <input _ngcontent-c8="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-model="0" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-primary" ngbtooltip="Alterar célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Alterar célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-danger" ngbtooltip="Apagar célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Apagar célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-info" ngbtooltip="Configuração de célula" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/configuracao-celula" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Configuração de célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-wrench"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-secondary" ngbtooltip="Campos da célula" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/campos" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Campos da célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-list"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-dark" ngbtooltip="Tabulações da célula" placement="top" type="button" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Tabulações da célula">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-bookmark"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td _ngcontent-c8="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c8="" class="btn btn-warning" ngbtooltip="Configurar Pausa" placement="top" type="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/motivos-pausa,57" ng-reflect-placement="top" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="Configurar Pausa">
                            <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="oi oi-media-pause"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared it is not clear which element resembles to the **round slider** icon. To click on the **round slider** as the element is an [**Angular**](https://angular.io/) element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath(("//td[contains(.,'célula 1')]//following::td[1]/label//span[@class='slider round']")).click();
//or
driver.findElement(By.Xpath(("//td[contains(.,'célula 1')]//following::td[1]/label/input[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid' and @type='checkbox']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to handle these types of controls is by creating a map for yourself. Something like this:

```
private Map<String, WebElement> buttonsMap = new HashMap<String, WebElement>();

private void createButtonsMap() {
    // find your table - adjust the locator as needed!
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("w-100"));
    // find every row in the table
    List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for (WebElement tableRow : tableRows) {
        // find every data cell in each row
        List<WebElement> tableDatas = tableRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        try {
            // find the "name" for each row; something like "célula 1"
            String name = tableDatas.get(0).getText();
            // find your button
            WebElement button = tableDatas.get(1).findElement(By.tagName("button"));
            // store both in the map
            buttonsMap.put(name, button);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

The `try..catch` is needed to account for the fact that the very first row does not have a button.

Then to click on any button you just need:

```
public void clickButton(String name) {
    buttonsMap.get(name).click();
}
```

If you are using PageObjects, then you would want to call the `createButtonsMap()` from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!