# Finding an element based on its neighbor elements' text in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So as the title suggests my problem is that I need to find a selectbox based on its neighbors name. Let me show you the structure. It is something like this. There exists multiple divs that contain an image on left, a title and a selectbox. So I need to find the selectbox that's inside of a div in which the title is let's say "A Title". I didn't know what to search on Google, therefore I wanted to post it here. Thanks beforehand.

[image]

Comment: Such design can be created in many ways, so please post html code rather than picture.

Comment: Once you figure out the DOM, have a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51213672/3124333 if it will help you.

Comment: can you give us a link? Maybe i can help you

Comment: Add html code so that we get to know more about the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this approach:

a. following -> Select all input after attribute

```
//tagName[@attribute=’’]//following::tagName
```

b. following-sibling -> Select sibling element

```
//tagName[@attribute=’’]//following-sibling::tagName
```

c. ancestor -> Select ancestor of current element

```
//tagName[@attribute=’’]//ancestor::tagName
```

d. child -> select child of current element

```
//tagName[@attribute=’’]//child::tagName
```

e. Preceding -> Select preceding elements

```
//tagName[@attribute=’’]//preceding::tagName
```

f. Parent -> Select parent of current element

```
//tagName[@attribute=’’]//parent::tagName
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below approach:

Let the product container be `<div class="container"></div>` tag whose children are Title and Select. Let title and select be `<div class="title">A Title</div>` and `<div type="submit"></div>`

Now you can write a common dynamic xpath linking title and select elements as below:

**Xpath for 'Select' element if title and select elements are not following or preceding siblings to each other:**

`//div[@type="submit" and parent::div[@class="container" and child::div[@class="title"]]]`

**Xpath for 'Select' element if title element is preceding sibling of select element:**

`//div[@type="submit" and preceding-sibling::div[@class="title"]]`

**Xpath for 'Select' element if title element is following sibling of select element:**

`//div[@type="submit" and following-sibling::div[@class="title"]]`